# Formatting dynamically created column

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a asp grid contents generated dynamically using a sql procedure.
using the procedure  datatable returned is binded to the grid. In this grid i have a cost column which I like to round to 4 decimal places(12.1234). How to do the same?

I tried in RowDataBound as

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
   e.Row.Cells[4].Text = string.Format("{0:N4}", e.Row.Cells[4].Text);
}
```

But this has no effect. I cannot apply the formatting to datatable as I am using this for cost calculations so rounding the cost could cause problems.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: why do you have asp-classic tagged?  This looks like .net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should convert your variable type from `string` to `decimal`/`double` type and then apply your format:

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
   e.Row.Cells[4].Text = Convert.ToDecimal(e.Row.Cells[4].Text).ToString("#.####");
}
```